# How would a car move if it has two different tire sizes

Tags: rear-differential

Suppose a rear wheel car which has front to tires and left tire on the rear are same diameter and the right rear tire is slightly larger. 3 questions

1. How would the car move if it is driven?
2. Does the differential neutralise the tire size difference?
3. If so would the car move at the same speed as intended?

Comment: You should probably add a 4th question - "Will this cause damage?"

Comment: Another concern is will it effect handling and braking?

Answer (score 1):

1. How would the car move if it is driven?
      It will move in the direction decided by the position of the front wheels.

2.
    Does the differential neutralise the tire size difference?
      The differential will accommodate the rotational difference.

3. If so would the car move at the same speed as intended?
     Yes, the speed will be controlled by the engine output ie throttle position.